# Sony Vaio webcam (VGP-VCC6) is no longer working (not detected)

Tags: windows-vista, webcam, sony-vaio

I have a Sony Vaio laptop with Windows Vista Home Premium Version 2 with a 32 bit operating system.  I have no idea what has caused my internal webcam (VGP-VCC6) to cease working, but my system can no longer detect the camera.  Additionally, I have attempted to install an external Kodak camera and neither can it be detected.  The device manager has an exclamation point next to the imaging devices listed, Lexmark 7100 series and Sony Visual Communication Camera VGP-VCC6.

In my attempt to correct this problem I have uninstalled the driver and reinstalled it directly in the device manager screen as well as gone to Sony's website and searched for the driver and downloaded it.  Neither worked (note when I uninstall the devise I get an explanation point next to the following: USB video device).

As I stated, I have also installed an external webcam that did not work, which leads me to believe this is not a hardware related issue.  I can not put my finger on any specific change, system or application update that caused this to stop working.  I only realized it was an issue after attempting to Skype with my family and they were unable to see me.  In the tools video section for Skype it says unable to detect a webcam.

Comment: This would appear to be a defect with the Sony Vaio and the Sony Visual Communication Camera. If you are under warranty take it back. If not, complain to Sony.